# Postgresql stored procedure debug

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I am trying to find on net and it seems that there is a plugin I need to install which will enable a debug option in pgadmin3 but I can't see any such option.. How can I debug Postgresql stored procedure ?

Comment: Here is similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20190406/how-to-debug-postgresql-stored-procedures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to install the [pldebugger](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=pldebugger.git;a=summary) on the PostgreSQL server.

After you have compiled and installed the extension, you must add `plugin_debugger` to `shared_preload_libraries` in `postgresql.conf` and restart the database server.

Then you can debug functions with pgAdmin.